# No more free downvotes?

Tags: discussion, reputation, down-votes, daily-reputation-limit

Today I got more than 200 rep points in upvotes (in SO, not meta).

But when I downvote some answers (because I feel it's needed), my reputation is decreasing.

Did that change just recently or am I missing something ?

Comment: Downvoting answers has been costing -1 point for a while now.

Comment: I thought the 200 reputation cap was protecting against it and making those downvotes free...

Comment: Nope, there's no buffer from the cap. If you hit the cap and get a downvote, you're at 198.

Comment: See [Rep cap allows to cast free answer downvotes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136919/rep-cap-allows-to-cast-free-answer-downvotes)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's not new. Your downvote costs are compensated by upvotes you receive *after* you voted down (or were voted down), though, until you are again at 200 rep points from upvotes.

Comment: Ok... So I cannot go to bed now... and I was yet beginning to feel dizzy from the vine... :D

Comment: Why can't you go to bed?

Comment: Because I *need* to regain this point. Ok, that was just a joke...

Answer (score 3):

Down votes on answers cost rep.  Down votes on questions do not.